# :hover with linear gradients in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, hover, css3pie, linear-gradients

The design for this button calls for it to have a linear gradient, but then when you hover over it, the button should go to a flat color. The main class looks like this, and it seems to work find in all the browsers I've tested it in. As you can see, I'm also using PIE to make the gradient work properly in lower IE browsers.

```
.mvcView.button.texture {
        background-color: #F34914;
        border-width: 0px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 4px;

        min-width: 40px;
        overflow:visible;   /*overflow visible is required for ie 7 to respect min-width and doesn't seem to affect other browsers.  */
        width : auto;
        vertical-align: middle;

        font-family: Arial;
        background-color: #F34914;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F34914, #8A2800);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F34914, #8A2800);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F34914, #8A2800);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F34914, #8A2800);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #F34914, #8A2800);
       -pie-background: linear-gradient(#F34914, #8A2800);

       behavior: url('/PIE.htc');
}
```

For webkit browsers, the following css changes the color to be flat on mouseover:

```
.mvcView.button.texture:hover {
    background: #AA3200;
}
```

For IE9, the hover only works if I do it this way:

```
.mvcView.button.texture:hover {
    background: #AA3200;
    background-color: #AA3200;
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#AA3200, #AA3200);

    behavior: url('/PIE.htc');
}
```

Is there another, more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that this is a PIE bug. I am having the same problem. If you assigned the PIE behavior to a css class or id, it looks like you cannot just `#id:hover{background:#some-color;}`,because its expecting the `-pie-background` as well, which you already defined as a gradient for example, so it is normal that it works on all browsers, except IE, since PIE is designed especially for that. A workaround, is to style the parent using PIE(adding rounded corners, shadows, gradients), and add a child that will inherit the parent width and height, and style it with or without PIE and `background:none;`(no gradients). Then for the child simply do `.child:hover{background:#some-solid-color;}`. So if its a button you are styling, when normal, it will be filled with whatever parent pie gradient you defined, and when hovered, since the child "overlays"(so to speak) the parent, it will show a solid color. Of course this goes against my better judgement when deeply nesting divs or whatever other elements. On the other hand, the solution you posted above for IE9, also does the trick(IE 6-8 too). Though i have no idea which of the 2 solutions is less counter-productive, if i had to take a guess, i think adding a gradient-less child would be better.

Comment: Upon further experimenting with PIE, if you use PIE 2.0 beta, you can do it like this `#element:hover{-pie-background:#some-solid-color;}`(no gradient needed). Still you have to use the -pie prefix.

Comment: I don't have access to that code anymore to try it out and see if you're right, but I suspect you are! Thanks for solving the mystery.

Answer (score 0):

A gradient is some kinda image so if you set up a gradient, you could do it this way

```
.button {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#F34914, #8A2800);
}

.button:hover {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #AA3200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/** DON'T FORGET ABOUT <element class="ahover"><span>Text</span></a> IF U USE TEXT ELEMENT *//

.ahover {
display: block;
/** text-indent: -999em; ** if u use only only img **/
position: relative;
}
.ahover:after {
content: "";
height: 100%;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
.ahover:hover:after {
opacity: 1;
}
.ahover span {
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: 3 }
```